# Adding animation on Event trigger

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Basically, I want to add animation when I remove an item from the state, or when I press the button. I would really appreciate the help. Thank you.

```
const Control = ({close}) => {
const {remove, icons }= useGlobalContext()
    return ( 
        <div className='control'>
          <div className='close__cont'>
            <GrClose className='close' onClick={close} />
            <h3>Control</h3>
          </div>
          <div className='control__cont'>
            {icons.map((unin)=> {            
              const { name, img, id} = unin         
                return (               
                 <li className='control' key={id}>
                  <div className='img__text'> 
                    <img className='control__Img' src={img} />             
                    <h4 className='control__name'>{name}</h4>
                  </div>             
                <button className='unin__button'  onClick={(e) => {
                 e.stopPropagation();
                 remove(id) }}>remove</button>   
              </li> 
               )                                            
          })}         
          </div>             
        </div>                 
    )
}

export default Control
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside javascript in the onclick function you have mentioned above you can write `document.getElementById("unin__button").style.animation ="name for animation, duration, iteration count"`. When writing there is no need for the commas between animation, duration and iteration count, and also you'll have to define the animation in css .